# Multiple peaks data fitting. How to effectively fit different distributions in the same data?

Tags: python, distribution, gaussian, model-fitting

I have this data of hydrogen desorption as a function of temperature, that has 4 peaks:
[image: Hydrogen vs Temperature]

I want to fit a distribution curve to each peak to extract information like area below each peak. For peaks 1, 2 and 3 I think a Gaussian fit works well:
[image: Gaussian fittings]

I use the first code to get first values of parameters and the second to define the final parameters:

```
# Fitting procedure

def fitting_procedure(xdata, ydata):
    
    # fitting function
    def func(xdata, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4):     #
        return a1 * np.exp(-0.5*(((xdata-b1)**2)/(c1**2)))+ \
               a2 * np.exp(-0.5*(((xdata-b2)**2)/(c2**2)))+ \
               a3 * np.exp(-0.5*(((xdata-b3)**2)/(c3**2)))+ \
               a4 * np.exp(-0.5*(((xdata-b4)**2)/(c4**2)))
        
#     p0 = [0.002, 505, 1, 0.002, 780, 1, 0.002, 725, 1, 0.002, 975, 1] # for file 01    
#     p0 = [0.002, 510, 1, 0.002, 650, 1, 0.002, 740, 1, 0.002, 840, 1]
    p0 = [0.002, 570, 1, 0.002, 668, 1, 0.002, 800, 1, 0.002, 820, 1]

    bounds = ((0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.),
             (np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf))

    cons, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0, bounds=bounds, maxfev=1000000)
    
    return (cons)
```

```
def gas(y0,A,w,xc):
    return y0 + (A/(w*math.sqrt(math.pi/2)))*np.exp(-2*((x-xc)/w)**2)
```

But for the 3rd peak, I think a lognormal fitting works well. However I am having difficult creating a good fitting:

```
model = models.LognormalModel()
params = model.make_params(center=20, sigma=3, amplitude=5)

result = model.fit(y14-0.003, params, x=x14)
# print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x14, y14-0.003, label='3rd peak')
plt.plot(x14, result.best_fit, label='fit')
# plt.plot(x14_fit, y14_fit, label='fit2')
plt.xlabel('Temperature, K', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('HDR, at.ppm/s', fontsize=12)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Lognormal fitting - 3rd peak] and
[image: Total fittings]

How can I improve my fittings, especially for the third peak?

Thanks,
Maria